# Is "keep out each other's hair" wrong?

Tags: expressions

I found a expression: "Keep out of each other's hair".

Is it wrong if I say without "of"? I mean, is "Keep out each other's hair" is correct sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, you need that ***of***.  Your version is basically wrong.

Technically, I think your version *is* grammatical, but it means something very different, something people [don't say very often](https://goo.gl/bTexrs):

> *Alice:* Okay, let's go in the pool!
>   *Bob:* Sure!  But wait, the pool's full of bleach!
>   *Alice:* Bleach?
>   *Bob:* Yeah!  And you don't want that on your hair!
>   *Alice:* And we *do* want it on our skin?
>   *Bob:* Never mind that!  The important thing is not to get it on our hair!
>   *Alice:* And as you know, Bob, we're forbidden from touching our own hair by religious mandate!
>   *Bob:* That's right, so I'll keep your hair out of the pool, and *you* keep *mine* out of it!
>   *Alice:* So we'll both **keep out each other's hair**?
>   *Bob:* That's right!

That's the closest I can come to making sense of it.

In other words, if you remove ***of***, it would no longer be the idiomatic expression you learned, and it'd be a stretch to come up with a context where it'd be possible to say.

So don't remove that ***of***.  You need it!

Comment: In addition to snailboat's great answer (and hilarious!), I'd like to add the definitions of *keep out* and *keep out of* given by Macmillan Dictionary: [keep out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/keep-out) "prevent someone or something from entering a place"; [keep out of](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/keep-out-of) "to not become involved with something".

Comment: And the prize for most contrived but completely accurate example in a situation where it seems that there are no natural examples goes to... \*drumroll\* :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Actually, I think you should add that as an answer: adding the definition of both phrases definitely contributes.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the `of`, like dropping `that`, is colloquially acceptable in some places.

However, in the main, it is a part of the sentence. To be formal, and to be unambiguous (see snailboat's answer), you should keep it.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I notice that dropping the 'of' is something some US English speakers (that I have no reason to believe are particularly ungrammatical) do.

Comment: It's kind of a regional thing in the US. In my experience they drop "of" in the southeast quite a bit. At least in Louisiana and Alabama.